# How to force JFrame windows theme on all OS's

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, jframe

I have an issue with developing a GUI for my java application. I develop on Windows and use windows based programs. However when a user on a Mac or linux OS uses the GUI it has different layouts and some fields are pushed off the frame. Is there a way I can force a GUI to use a specific system theme?

Comment: You can use to choose something like nimbus, which is, now, the default, cross platform look and feel

Answer (score 0):

The [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) on Look and Feel has some pretty good examples on how to set the LnF programmatically.

In a nutshell, call

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("fully qualified name of the lnf");
```

at the beginning of your main() method. For example, if you wanted to use the cross-platform LnF, you'd use

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Comment: For the cross-platform LnF, he'd use `getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName`. Also, he wants to use the Windows LnF, which isn't installed on any/most computers with Mac or Linux.

Comment: @Lonenebula You're absolutely right on the cross-platform lnf. I grabbed the wrong method name. Corrected now.